# Separating the components of an image and saving them as new image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, crop

I have a black and white image as shown below:

[image: inputimage]

I want to separate the white components of this image and then save them as separate image. This image has four white parts. I want to separate them and save four new images; each containing a white part of the image.

To achieve this, I wrote the following code:

```
BW=imread('img11_Inp.jpg');
imshow(BW);
BW=imbinarize(BW);

[L, num] = bwlabel(BW);
for k = 1 : num
    thisBlob = ismember(L, k);
    h = int2str(k);
    filname = strcat(h,'_Out.jpg');
    imwrite(thisBlob,filname);
    figure
    imshow(thisBlob, []);
end
```

## Problem

This code separates the white parts and saves them but the size of the white part saved in the new image is same as in the original image. See the output images below:

## Output images

[image: out1]
[image: out2]
[image: out3]
[image: out4]

## Desired Output images

I want the output images to contain increased size of the white part of the original image. Following images are the ones I want:

[image: reqout1]
[image: reqout2]
[image: reqout3]
[image: reqout4]

## Question

How can I modify the above code so that I can get the desired output images ?

Comment: How much black do you want to keep in an image?

Comment: as much as shown in the desired output images

Comment: Define it in exact numbers/pixels. What if white is at the edge in the original image? Would you still want to have black on the sides of it?

Comment: There is no fixed number of black pixels that i want to show around the white part. Black pixels in the output image should be only as much so that some black colour is visible around the white part of the image. No i don't want to show the black on the sides if white part is at the edge of the original image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what you want to perform is a crop with a little bit of span around the object. This can be easily achieved using `imcrop` that you must call providing the rectangle you want to keep.

In order to identify the rectangle:

1. Find the minimum an maximum rows that contain a white pixel (`y-axis`);
2. Find the minimum an maximum columns that contain a white pixel (`x-axis`);
3. Calculate width and height of the rectangle using `maximum - minimum`.
4. Since you want to crop using a little `margin` (in my example I set its value to `10` but you have full control over it), you must subtract that `margin` to minimum values and adding it to maximum values, but paying attention not to go out of the boundaries of the image (that's where the little `min-max` game comes into play).

Here is the full working code:

```
img = imread('img11_Inp.jpg');
imshow(img);

img_bin = imbinarize(img);
[lab,num] = bwlabel(img_bin);

span = 10;

for k = 1:num
    file = [num2str(k) '_Out.jpg'];

    blob = ismember(lab,k);
    blob_size = size(blob);

    col_idx = find(any(blob == true,1));
    x1 = max([1 (min(col_idx) - span)]);
    x2 = min([blob_size(2) (max(col_idx) + span)]);
    width = x2 - x1;

    row_idx = find(any(blob == true,2));
    y1 = max([1 (min(row_idx) - span)]);
    y2 = min([blob_size(1) (max(row_idx) + span)]);
    height = y2 - y1;

    blob_crop = imcrop(blob,[x1 y1 width height]);
    imwrite(blob_crop,file);

    figure();
    imshow(blob_crop,[]);
end
```

Also, don't use `int2str(k)` in order to obtain a string representation of your index. Your index is actually a `double` so you are forcing a double (no pun intended) cast: `double -> int` and then `int -> char array`. Just use `num2str`.

Result:

[image: Crop]

Answer (score 1):

### Steps:

1. Find the boundary of the white portion.
2. To include the black portion, subtract a constant from the top left corner.If it is less than or equal to zero, it means we have reached or exceeded the left corner of the actual image, so set it 1. If it is greater than zero then all is fine.
3. Make similar adjustments for the right bottom corner.
4. Crop to the desired size.

### Code:

```
%Finding the boundary of the white
[~, c1] = find(thisBlob, 1);             [~, r1] = find(thisBlob.', 1);
[~, c2] = find(thisBlob, 1, 'last');     [~, r2] = find(thisBlob.', 1, 'last');

%Making adjustments to include the black portion
k = 10;            %constant defining max number of black pixels
mxlim = size(X);   %to be used to confirm that we don't exceed the boundary of the image
r1 = r1-10;  r1(r1<=0)=1;                    c1 = c1-10;  c1(c1<=0)=1;
r2 = r2+10;  r2(r2>mxlims(1)) = mxlim(1);    c2 = c2+10;  c2(c2>mxlim(2)) = mxlims(2);

%Extracting the desired portion
thisBlob = thisBlob(r1:r2, c1:c2);
```

### Output for the provided images:

[image: output1]  [image: output2]  [image: output3]  [image: output4]

You can change the number of black pixels by changing the constant `k` in the code.

---

### Test Case when the white portion is on the Edge:

To verify if it also works if the white portion is on the edge like this image:

[image: input2]

The code gives the following output for the above image:

[image: output5]

Comment: do i need to add this code to my current code or is this the complete code that i can use in place of the one that i have written ?

Comment: @Nick The above code assumes that you have already separated the white portions and explains the further processing. You need to add this code after the line `filname = strcat(h,'_Out.jpg');`